# Generated Identifier Too Long For Constraint Name

Tags: mysql, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3

I am just getting started with Entity Framework (4.3.1) and am making a code-first model with TPT inheritance using the MySQL EF provider (6.5.4). When attempting to create the database structure, I am receiving a `MySQLException "Identifier name 'LongClassNameOne_TypeConstraint_From_ClassName2s_To_LongClassNameOnes' is too long"` (This is the relation which relates the derived class's table to the parent class's table.)

```
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int32& insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int32& insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlScript.Execute()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseOperations.Create(ObjectContext objectContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext objectContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Database.Create()
   at System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseAlways`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Database.<>c__DisplayClass2`1.<SetInitializerInternal>b__0(DbContext c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClass8.<PerformDatabaseInitialization>b__6()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ForceOSpaceLoadingForKnownEntityTypes()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext()
   ...
```

How can I control this name to make it shorter, or force it to be trimmed to the 64-character name limit, or something along these lines?

Comment: Evil problem. I can't answer the question, but for SQL Server I have never seen a way to control and customize the constraint names. I am even not sure who is responsible and who to blame for the name: Entity Framework itself or the MySQL provider?

Comment: I don't have environment in front of me - but this might help (if you might need more I'll post an answer later on today) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829636(v=vs.103).aspx - and possibly this link - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/2b182758-ef29-4407-b62b-12aee816aa45. i.e. you could set your own `SqlGenerator` and then there are overrides for various SQL generation parts - but I'm unsure if this covers what you need.

Comment: @NSGaga - If you overwrite SqlGenerator and change names your database may never match the model generated by CodeFirst and you may run into a lot of weird problems that will be hard to solve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use shorter table name as there is no way to configure names of constraints. Note that you don't need to change class names to do that. You can either use Table attribute or use .ToTable() method in OnModelCreating.

Comment: I posted the actual solution I had in mind - the link was wrongly pointing to table change (as I was in a hurry from a device) - but what I meant is changing the relation name - which should have no consequences. Table name mapping is easiest solution still - fully agree (+1) - if desirable.

Comment: I chose to specify a shorter table name via the annotation attribute. This kinda stinks though, since this project involves a base library which other people use. It is annoying to have to resort to this. My table names are not really even all that long....

Answer (score 6):

To expand on my comment earlier on...

If you can just change the table name - then go with the mapping in the OnModelCreating - `as @Pawel suggested`, that's likely the easiest solution of all.

However, if you'd like to change just the name of the relation,

...by providing a custom `SqlGenerator` (i.e. the `SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator`) in the `Configuration()` you can micro-manage the actual sql generated when needed (and that might be the generic, automated solution in some general case). e.g.

```
public class MySqlGenerator : SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator
{
    protected override void Generate(AddForeignKeyOperation addForeignKeyOperation)
    {
        if (addForeignKeyOperation.Name == "LongClassNameOne_TypeConstraint_From_ClassName2s_To_LongClassNameOnes")
            addForeignKeyOperation.Name = "MyCustomFKName";
        // addForeignKeyOperation.Name = "Test" + addForeignKeyOperation.Name;
        base.Generate(addForeignKeyOperation);
    }
}
```

...or something along those lines (you need to match, find the right naming - or compare the `Name Length` and shorten it where needed. And in your Configuration (file generated by migrations)...

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    SetSqlGenerator("MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator", new MySqlGenerator());
    // SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new MySqlGenerator());
}
```

(note: I don't know for sure but it was suggested (by @Mariusz Jamro) that the MySQL provider's name is `MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator`, makes sense I guess)

...this should change the FK of the relation - and as far as could test this fast it works ok, as the relation name is not really used in the model from C# (just a db name normally).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but I think I'll just shorten the table names and live with it. I was hoping another solution might be to shorten that name, but it appears this is in the EF code, not the MySQL provider. If it were in the MySQL provider, I would have gone that route instead, as I have already needed to fix 2 other bugs in the provider to get this working.

Comment: np - that's easier I agree - the right place to fix 'too long relations' would be around sql code generation (as EF/CF generates those names which are too long for MySQL seems - so MySQL's fault is that it can't accept those identifiers, but EF is 'causing' it). I didn't get your reasoning above. But I'd pick the 'easy way out' (table names), and resort to fixing sql generation if you have that repeating over time.

Comment: The MySQL generator name is `MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator`